# Getting data for replacement (python 3.3)

Tags: python, string, replace

For example, I have a string or a list of such strings:

```
text = '000 #-tags-2-7-# 001 002 003 004 05 06 07 08 SDFGSDFG #-tags-3-9-#'
keys = ['key-1', 'key-2', 'key-3', 'key-4', 'key-5', 'key-6', 'key-7', 'key-8', 'key-9', 'key-10']
```

and I need to replace #-tags-2-7-# on result from `keys[randint(2, 7)]` and #-tags-3-9-# on `keys[randint(2, 7)]` etc. I need to get every time two integers from #-tags-*-*-# and send it to `keys[randint(*, *)]` and send result instead #-tags-*-*-#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [re.sub](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to replace the pattern `r'#-tags-(\d)-(\d)-#'` with the desired string:

```
import re
import random
text = '000 #-tags-2-7-# 001 002 003 004 05 06 07 08 SDFGSDFG #-tags-3-9-#'
keys = ['key-1', 'key-2', 'key-3', 'key-4', 'key-5', 'key-6', 'key-7', 'key-8', 'key-9', 'key-10']

def tag_replace(match):
    start, end = map(int, match.groups())
    return ', '.join(random.sample(keys, random.randint(start, end)))

print(re.sub(r'#-tags-(\d)-(\d)-#', tag_replace, text))
```

prints (a random result such as)

```
000 key-8, key-7, key-3 001 002 003 004 05 06 07 08 SDFGSDFG key-9, key-1, key-7, key-3, key-4, key-10, key-6
```

Note: I take that you want `#-tags-3-9-#` to be replaced by a comma-separated list of `n` items from `keys`, where `n = random.randint(3, 9)`.

Comment: #-tags-3-9-# means to insert that 3 or 4 or 5 ... or 9 strings from "keys" with separator "," or something. in the same way should be processed and replaced other #-tags- - -#

Comment: need somehow to get parameters from "tags" for to know how many random string need to get from "keys"